# WSO2 DAS with Postgres

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I am trying to change the WSO2 DAS data source from H2 to postgres.

I have configured all the database changes in master-datasource.xml,analytics-datasource.xml and metrics.xml

The below exception is being thrown while creating an event stream

---

```
java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /eventstream/inner_event_stream_persistence_ui.jsp at line 38

35:     EventStreamPersistenceAdminServiceStub persistenceAdminServiceInnerStub =
36:             EventStreamUIUtils.getEventStreamPersistenceAdminService(config, session, request);
37:     if (EventStreamUIUtils.isEventStreamPersistenceAdminServiceAvailable(persistenceAdminServiceInnerStub)) {
38:         String[] recordStoreNames = persistenceAdminServiceInnerStub.listRecordStoreNames();
39:         pageContext.setAttribute("recordStoreNames", recordStoreNames, PageContext.PAGE_SCOPE);
40:     }
41: %>

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method listRecordStoreNames
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.stream.persistence.stub.EventStreamPersistenceAdminServiceStub.listRecordStoreNames(EventStreamPersistenceAdminServiceStub.java:227)
        at org.apache.jsp.eventstream.create_005fevent_005fstream_jsp._jspService(create_005fevent_005fstream_jsp.java:282)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
----------------------
```

Please help to solve this issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could you please double check the configs on "[DAS_HOME]/repository/conf/analytics/analytics-config.xml" file. You could refer to [1] and [2] for more details on the configs.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Datasources

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Configuring+Data+Persistence

Best Regards,

Milinda.